# Can an Aadhaar card be used as a proof of ID to travel to Nepal?

Tags: indian-citizens, international-travel, nepal, identity-cards

I don't have any of the specified documents for travelling to Nepal as an identity proof. Can I use an [Aadhaar card](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aadhaar) instead as proof of identity?

Answer (score 1):

**No**, Aadhar Card is not a valid identity proof, you require a Valid National Passport when travelling to any other country(in your case Nepal).

Identity documents required for Indian Citizen going to / coming from Nepal by Air :-

- Valid National Passport.
- Photo Identity card issued by the Government of India/State Govt./UT Administration in India to their employees or Election ID card issued by the Election Commission of India.
- Emergency Certificate issued by Embassy of India, Kathmandu.
- Identity Certificate issued by Embassy of India, Kathmandu.
- Persons in the age of group of above 65 years and below 15 years would be exempted from the requirement of approved identity documents mentioned above. However, they must have some documents with photograph to confirm their age and identity such as PAN card, Driving license, CGHS card, Ration card etc.
- Children between the age group of 15 to 18 years may be allowed to travel between India and Nepal on the strength of Identity certificate issued by the principal of the school in the prescribed performa.

Please visit the [link](http://boi.gov.in/content/indian-passengers) below for further information.

Comment: An Indian voter's Registration Card is also valid for Nepal, but that's it